# View Mac files on Windows server 03 and Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, mac-osx-server

I wanted to know if this is possible at all. Here's the scenario I have a location in New Jersey that is using a Mac Server, with one windows server there for file replication we will call this (Location A), and I use all Windows servers in Arizona we will call this (Location B).

What I'm trying to do is view the files on the Mac Server at location A without using Windows file replication due to location A has to move the files from the Mac server to the file replication server they have there. Which at times is very difficult for them to get to due to there work loads there. So to avoid the long wait for files we would like to grab them from the Mac Server.

We are looking for something that doesn't require Location A to interact with moving the files for location B.

What do you all suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably map a drive or a share depending on the connection you have between location A and B. Probably something like a VPN.

If you can mount a drive on your Windows to your Mac server, you can probably use one of these softwares to check the files :

http://www.macdisk.com/mden.php

or

http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm

I only use Transmac so far to read Mac files on Windows 7 and it did the job ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Mac OS X Server, you should be able to create a SMB share. I don't have a Mac server in front of me, but I believe it's in Server Preferences-->File Sharing. Once shared, your PCs should be able to get to the drive directly by mapping the drive on the client.

If you're just using a regular Mac as a server without the Server software, you can still enable Samba at the Unix level, or use [SharePoints](http://www.hornware.com/sharepoints/) as a GUI to set up a Windows share.

Comment: I thought of the SMB shares method. But is this possible to do with the Mac Server being located in New Jersey and I'm in Arizona?

Comment: I'm assuming (I know, bad idea) that you are able to access SMB shares in location B already. If you can't, then this question is more network-related, and we need more info on what network services besides file replication are available between A & B.

Comment: I have a VPN tunnel that connects New Jersey Location A to Arizona Location B. Location A has a sunbnet ip address of location B. I can see the replication sever just fine but beyond that I cant see anything to my knowledge.

Comment: I guess I need more info. If you can't even ping the Mac server from AZ, then you've got network configuration to do so that the NJ Mac server is visible to AZ clients. Of course, you'll have some bandwidth and latency issues going through the VPN, but that's unavoidable.

If you can get that network issue sorted out, then you should be able to set up the share with my answer above.